# Can you have a final ELSE when dealing with Count and Case in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Name, RecDate,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Note LIKE '%Highly Recommend%' THEN 1 END) "5 Star",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Note LIKE '%would recommend%' THEN 1 END) "4 Star",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Note LIKE '%had no issues%' THEN 1 END) "3 Star",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Note LIKE '%would not recommend%' THEN 1 END) "2 Star",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Note LIKE '%would definitely not recommend%' THEN 1 END) "1 Star",
FROM
        Surveys
GROUP BY
        Name, RecDate
```

However, I'm having trouble thinking of the way to say "ELSE if none of those, then '0 Star'". How would I do this as part of this query please?

Comment: Invert your logic. `CASE WHEN Note LIKE '%Highly recommend%' THEN '5 Star' WHEN Note LIKE '%would recommend%' THEN '4 Star' ... ELSE '0 Star' END`, then `GROUP BY` (and `PIVOT` if you must).

Comment: it could be (depending on the data/specs) :  `"0 stars" = "all rows::count(*)" - "5 star" - "4 star" -.....-"1 star"`